# ChangeNotifierProxyProvider0 returns the error Failed assertion: line 125 pos 28: 'value.hasListeners != true': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am not able to use `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`.

I have a `StreamBuilder` (list of items) and I need to update a single item when something changes.
This is the part of the widget with `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`:

```
return StreamBuilder<List<MyItem>>(
  stream: _listStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 3.0);
        break;
      default:
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length > 0) {
          return ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            controller: _controller,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length + 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return index >= snapshot.data.length
                  ? CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 3.0)
                  : ChangeNotifierProxyProvider0<MyItem>(
                create: (context) => snapshot.data[index],
                update: (_, item) => item,
                child: Consumer<MyItem>(
                  builder: (_, value, __) {
                    return ListTile(title: value.title);
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
    }
  },
);
```

This is `MyItem`:

```
class MyItem with ChangeNotifier {
    String title;

    void changeTitle(newT) {
        title = newT;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

In another part of the app I call `myItem.changeTitle` function.

The error I get is:

> Another exception was thrown:
> 'package:provider/src/listenable_provider.dart': Failed assertion:
> line 125 pos 28: 'value.hasListeners != true': is not true.
>
> The following assertion was thrown building Consumer<>(dirty,
> dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<>]):

**UPDATE**
It seems the error is:

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════ A MyItem was
> used after being disposed.

Occurred in the line of `Consumer` definition

Comment: the concerned error will be on top the error stack, `Another exception was thrown` means it isn't the first error and it might be because of the first error, please post the first error or the whole stack